# Just the Rug (Plot) in ggplot2? Alternatives?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'd like to make just a rug plot where each series is plotted as a horizontal band of ticks, similar to the plot shown [on this page](https://sites.google.com/site/spiketrainanalysiswithr/Home/analysis-gallery/e060517/e060517ionon-2). I've seen this called a "Raster Plot" as well. The rug plot looks similar but it looks like geom_rug only works for the margins. Can I get a raster plot in GGplot2? If not, is there a way to do it in other R plotting packages? Obviously the package I linked could do this, but I'd prefer a reference to a pure graphical package and not a scientific analysis tool.

Update: my data would look like this:

```
 Time   Series  Value
 0.01   A   1.5
 0.01   B   0.78
 0.5    C   1.25
 0.75   A   1.5
 0.76   B   1.6
 0.76   C   0.2
 1  C   1.2
```

What I would expect is three vertical bands representing series A, B and C (y axis) and the x axis would be timescaled. For each series, at each timepoint I would see the tick-mark. The Value is not important to me at this time. I just want a visible indicator that Series X showed an event at time T.

Comment: Show us your data with `dput(your_data_frame)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `geom_point()` and set shape to `"|"` to produce vertical bands.

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(wt,cyl))+geom_point(shape="|",size=7)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 - other useful options are to make the pipes transparent and/or use jittering (depends on the goals of the plot though).